# Flutter Provider is not updating the PopupMenuButton itembuilder content and how to close the PopupMenu programatically

Tags: flutter, dart

> I am in the process of developing a header widget (like websites have) that consists of a
> PopupmenuButton in Flutter. This widget creates Popupmenumenuitems
> from the header data.
>
> I am unable to close the Popmenu programatically and update the
> content with in it. Is there any way to achieve this.

`Code PopupmenuDropdown`

```
List<Column> createChildrenTexts(BuildContext context) {
    List<Column> childrenTexts = List<Column>();
    for (MenuHeading name in headeComponents) {
      childrenTexts.add(Column(children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: PopupmenuDropdown(name, context),
        ),
      ]));
    }
    return childrenTexts;   }

  MouseRegion PopupmenuDropdown(MenuHeading name, BuildContext context) {
    final validationService = Provider.of<HeaderController>(context);
    // validationService.setmenuValues(name.name, name.dropdown);
    validationService.notifyNow(name.name, name.dropdown);
    GlobalKey dropdownKey = GlobalKey();
    PopupMenuButton menu = PopupMenuButton<String>(
      tooltip: name.name,
      child: Text(name.name + " " + validationService.count.toString(),
          style: AppTheme.h1()),
      elevation: 16,
      offset: Offset(0, 45),
      onSelected: (String url) {
        print("selected");
        // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/${url}');
      },
      onCanceled: () => print("called cancelle"),
      key: dropdownKey,
      itemBuilder: (_) => validationService.menuValues.containsKey(name.name)
          ? validationService.menuValues[name.name]
              .map<PopupMenuEntry<String>>((Menulisting value) {
              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: value.navigate,
                child: Text(value.name + validationService.count.toString(),
                    style: AppTheme.h1()),
              );
            }).toList()
          : [],
    );

    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (PointerEvent details) {
        dynamic stateerr = dropdownKey.currentState;
        stateerr.showButtonMenu();
      },
      onExit: (PointerEvent details) {
        // menu.initialValue = null;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          validationService.removeMenu(name.name);
        });
      },
      child: menu,
    );   }
```

> Full Code

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:myapp/controllers/headerCntrl.dart';
import 'package:myapp/models/headerModel.dart';
import 'package:myapp/styles/style.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class WebHeaders extends StatelessWidget {
  // final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<MenuHeading> headeComponents;
  BuildContext _drawerKey;

  WebHeaders() {
    // this._drawerKey = _drawerKey;
    this.headeComponents = [
      MenuHeading("Home", [], -45),
      MenuHeading(
          'Account',
          [
            Menulisting('Signups', 'signup'),
            Menulisting('Home2', 'home2'),
            Menulisting('ChangePassword', 'signup'),
            Menulisting('Settings', 'signup'),
          ],
          -45),
      MenuHeading(
          'Pages',
          [
            Menulisting('Pages', 'signup'),
            Menulisting('Pages1', 'signup'),
            Menulisting('Pages2', 'signup'),
          ],
          -45),
      MenuHeading(
          'Blog',
          [
            Menulisting('Blog', 'signup'),
            Menulisting('Blog1', 'signup'),
            Menulisting('Blog2', 'signup'),
          ],
          -45),
      MenuHeading(
          'Docs/ Components',
          [Menulisting('Docs', 'signup'), Menulisting('Components', 'signup')],
          -70),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle.merge(
      style: descTextStyle,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.menu,
                          color: Colors.red), // set your color here
                      onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                    ),
                    Text("Home Logo",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left, style: AppTheme.h1()),
                  ],
                )),
            Expanded(
                flex: 7,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: createChildrenTexts(context),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Column> createChildrenTexts(BuildContext context) {
    List<Column> childrenTexts = List<Column>();
    for (MenuHeading name in headeComponents) {
      childrenTexts.add(Column(children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: PopupmenuDropdown(name, context),
        ),
      ]));
    }
    return childrenTexts;
  }

  MouseRegion PopupmenuDropdown(MenuHeading name, BuildContext context) {
    final validationService = Provider.of<HeaderController>(context);
    // validationService.setmenuValues(name.name, name.dropdown);
    validationService.notifyNow(name.name, name.dropdown);
    GlobalKey dropdownKey = GlobalKey();
    PopupMenuButton menu = PopupMenuButton<String>(
      tooltip: name.name,
      child: Text(name.name + " " + validationService.count.toString(),
          style: AppTheme.h1()),
      elevation: 16,
      offset: Offset(0, 45),
      onSelected: (String url) {
        print("selected");
        // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/${url}');
      },
      onCanceled: () => print("called cancelle"),
      key: dropdownKey,
      itemBuilder: (_) => validationService.menuValues.containsKey(name.name)
          ? validationService.menuValues[name.name]
              .map<PopupMenuEntry<String>>((Menulisting value) {
              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: value.navigate,
                child: Text(value.name + validationService.count.toString(),
                    style: AppTheme.h1()),
              );
            }).toList()
          : [],
    );

    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (PointerEvent details) {
        dynamic stateerr = dropdownKey.currentState;
        stateerr.showButtonMenu();
      },
      onExit: (PointerEvent details) {
        // menu.initialValue = null;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
          validationService.removeMenu(name.name);
        });
      },
      child: menu,
    );
  }
}

class Header1 extends PreferredSize {
  IconData headerIcon;
  String headerName;
  Header1(this.headerIcon, this.headerName);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    if (screenSize.width <= 786) {
      return MobileHeaders(headerIcon, headerName);
    } else {
      return MultiProvider(providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => HeaderController()),
      ], child: WebHeaders());
    }
  }
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/models/headerModel.dart';

class HeaderController with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, List<Menulisting>> _menuValues = {};
  int count = 0;
  Map<String, List<Menulisting>> get menuValues => _menuValues;
  int get _count => count;

  //setters
  void notifyNow(String name, List<Menulisting> values) {
    if (count == 0) {
      if (_menuValues.isEmpty) {
        _menuValues[name] = values;
      } else {
        _menuValues[name] = values;
      }
    }
    // notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeMenu(String name) {
    count = 1;
    _menuValues.removeWhere((String key, value) => key == name);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}


import 'package:myapp/controllers/headerCntrl.dart';

class Dropdown1Object {
  String name;
  List<NavigateObject> dropdown;
  bool open;
  Dropdown1Object(this.name, this.dropdown);
}

class NavigateObject {
  String name;
  String navigate;
  NavigateObject(this.name, this.navigate);
}

class MenuHeading {
  String name;
  List<Menulisting> dropdown;
  double leftMargin;
  MenuHeading(this.name, this.dropdown, this.leftMargin);
}

class MenuItems {
  int name;
  HeaderController headerController;
  MenuItems(this.name, this.headerController);
}

class Menulisting {
  String name;
  String navigate;
  Menulisting(this.name, this.navigate);
}
```

### As I am also trying to achieve hoverable dropdown

[Page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GdW4.png)

Comment: `Navigator.pop(context)` will close the `PopupMenu`.

Comment: @Lee3 Navigator.pop(context) rebuilds widget leads to infinite loop.